# Apply vim color scheme to sudo root but not affecting other user sudo

Tags: linux, vim, centos, color-scheme

I downloaded and installed a custom color scheme for vim and successfully switched to it when I use vim.

Here is what I did:

1. Download color scheme monokai.vim
2. Put it under ~/.vim/colors
3. Update ~/.vimrc, append "colorscheme monokai"

When I use command `vim`, I can see monokai color scheme, however, when I use `sudo vim`, monokai is not showing.

How can I configure in order to apply monokai with `sudo vim` without affecting other users' `sudo vim`?
I don't want to force monokai color scheme globally.

Comment: Use `$ sudo -e` or `$ sudoedit` instead of `$ sudo vim`. See `$ man sudo`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, what about `sudo crontab -e` ? it opens two documents instead

Comment: `$ sudo -e filename` is an alternative to `$ sudo vim filename`, which is what your question is about. `crontab` works differently.